# Multiple functions in one list comprehension depending on conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I found a coding challenge on EdaBit:

> In a range of integers:
>
> 1. replace every number that is a multiple of 3 with `WORD`
> 2. replace every number that is a multiple of 5 with `EXAMPLE`
> 3. replace every number that is a multiple of 3 and 5 with `WORDEXAMPLE`
> 4. return them all in a list with the numbers which are not multiples of 3 and 5 in between.

I want to use a **list comprehension** to do this. I came up with this, which does not work:

```
return [i for i in range(start, end) if i%3 != 0 and i%5 != 0, "WORD" for i in range(start, end) if i%3==0 and i%5!=0, "EXAMPLE" for i in range(start, end) if i%3!=0 and i%5==0, "WORDEXAMPLE" for i in range(start, end) if if i%3==0 and i%5==0]
```

and I want it do be one list comprehension and not something like:

```
others = [i for i in range(start, end) if i%3 != 0 and i%5 != 0]
multiples_3 = ["WORD" for i in range(start, end) if i%3 == 0 and i%5 != 0]
multiples_5 = ["EXAMPLE" for i in range(start, end) if i%3 != 0 and i%5 == 0]
multiples_3_and_5 = ["WORDEXAMPLE" for i in range(start, end) if i%3 == 0 and i%5 == 0]
```

Generally speaking, can you create list comprehensions that use more than one function according to different conditionals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done (not advisable though, since it is difficult to read and understand). The code will be

```
numbers = range(1, 100) # Example
returned_list = ["WORDEXAMPLE" if i%(3*5)==0 else "WORD" if i%3==0  else "EXAMPLE" if i%5==0 else i for i in numbers]
```

In a list comprehension, you need to use multiple else statements (similar to elif statements otherwise).

Comment: This was exactely what I was looking for and I did not know you had to connect them with else statements...And yeah it looks rather complicated to read it too well but thanks a lot, this helped me along!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that takes care of all the logic like this:

```py
def relace_num(num):
    if num % (3*5) == 0:
        return 'WORDEXAMPLE'
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        return 'WORD'
    elif num % 5 == 0:
        return 'EXAMPLE'
    else:
        return num
```

And then use one list comprehension:

```py
 [relace_num(x) for x in range(start, end)]
```

Comment: Okay, yeah I am relatively new to python. I did not now you can use functions in list comprehensions...Looks very neat and legible. Many thanks!